# Check if the forEach Loop contains a value

Tags: angularjs

I have the following json

> success{   "fname": [
>       "The fname field is required."   ],   "lname": [
>       "The lname field is required."   ],   "email": [
>       "The email field is required."   ],   "password": [
>       "The password field is required."   ],   "password_confirmation": [
>       "The password confirmation field is required."   ] }

what i do is this,if the value contains field is required then console.log it. i saved the json in var data

```
 angular.forEach(data, function(value, key)
                {
                    if( value ==("field is required")){
                        console.log (key)
                    }
               })
```

I tried .contains, .match, nothing is working

Comment: Please review you json data, I notice the value actually is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also got the includes method.

Here the doc for includes : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

And the doc for IndexOf : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

I personally find the IndexOf solution a little dirty as it is not made for this, but it seems to be the most common solution.

You could also research in StackOverflow before asking, here is the answer of your question :

[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
                if( value.indexOf("field is required") > -1){
                    console.log (key)
                }
```

This will check if the string has "field is required".

Comment: i get this error : ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON vales are ["The --- field is required"] and you are testing string equality with "field is required", then your if condition will never evaluate to true.

You need to get the substring portion of your value if that is what you want to evaluate the condition on. You can use string split, search, substr, or another string method to get that portion of the value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

You need to use a regex with .match() or .search(). You could also use

```
 var idx = value.indexOf('field');
 var str = value.slice(idx);
 if( str == "field is required" )...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
  if(value.indexOf("field is required") > -1){
     console.log(key);
    }
 });
```

Comment: i get this error : ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null